# How to serially loop through multiple csv files from two directories and append them accordingly and plot from them in python?

Tags: pandas, loops, csv, matplotlib

I am trying make comparison bar plot for two types of variable and their count from csv files in python using `pandas` and `matplotlib`. Each type of variable data is stored in different directories. 
I have created two loops for both different data and `concate` them and plot them But there is a problem in looping and appending data. **First type of variable data is not appending with next file and it is taking 1st file always and concatenate with 2nd variable type data (which is appending correctly).**
Here is the code I am using

```
path = '/scratch/plots/'   
A_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*table.csv")))
path = '/scratch/plots/B/'   

B_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*table.csv")))


# loop through the files and read them in with pandas
dataframes = []  # a list to hold all the individual pandas DataFrames
for csvfile in A_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,usecols = ['COUNT','CLASS'])
    dataframes.append(df) #this case it is taking only first file to concate. Loop doest not appending correctly

dataframes2 = []
for x in B_files:
    fn= os.path.splitext(x)[0]
    df2 = pd.read_csv(x,usecols = ['COUNT','CLASS'])
    dataframes2.append(df2)

    A_df=df.iloc[2:12]
    B_df=df2.iloc[2:12]
    a= pd.concat([A_df,B_df], axis=1) 
    ax=a.set_index('CLASS').plot(kind='bar',rot=0, figsize=(15,10), fontsize=12)

    ax.legend(["A", "B"]);

    plt.savefig(''  + fn[:-32]+'_bargraph' + '.png', dpi=300)

    plt.show()
```

**How can I append through each file though 1st loop from the dictionary**  ? I have attached one example of concatenated data frame and plots [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KOGO.png)

Comment: I don't see any dictionary, do you mean dataframe? additionally, what do you want to loop over? i.e the class, the count ?

Comment: Are you looking for one single plot of all concatenated data frames or multiple plots for each pair of data in each directory?

Comment: @Parfait I have 2 files of 2 dates in one folder for one variable and similar 2 files in other folder of other variable. I concatenate Class(x-axis) and Count(y-axis) column from both of same dates to make a comparison plot. However first variable Class and Count is not concatenate with corresponding dates of other variable it is taking only 1st file and concatenate with other 2nd variable file. Please have a  look at the data in the image I have attached above.

Comment: Please see if proposed simultaneous loop below works for your needs.

Comment: @Parfait thank you so much  it worked. I have one more question- How can plot total CLASS (%) of A and B's categorical data into stacked bar side by side??? maybe using `.groupby` not by using `stacked=True` which is summing A and B Class in one bar in each CLASS (%). I want these total of 10-100% CLASS in one bar for A and 1 for B side by side.

Comment: That may be another question but look into seaborn's `barplot` with *hue* argument. But with this solution, your data must be long and not wide as you have it here (i.e., vertical with more rows instead of horizontal with more columns concatenation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looping through both directories at same time elementwise with `zip` (assuming equal amount of csv files in both directories) which may avoid the need to append data frames. Below makes no change to plotting:

```
for f1, f2 in zip(A_files, B_files):
    fn = os.path.splitext(f2)[0]

    # HORIZONTAL CONCATENATION
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f1, usecols = ['COUNT','CLASS']).iloc[2:12],
                    pd.read_csv(f2, usecols = ['COUNT','CLASS']).iloc[2:12]],
                   axis = 1)

    # PLOT
    ax = df.set_index('CLASS').plot(kind='bar', rot=0, figsize=(15,10), fontsize=12)    
    ax.legend(["A", "B"]);

    plt.savefig(fn[:-32]+'_bargraph' + '.png', dpi=300)   
    plt.show()
```